# how to open the setting of the device in click - android

Tags: android, setting

i work in app and want to add some buttons like dial button and setting button that when the user click on it will open the setting of the device

here is the code that opens the dial system on the device

```
 Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
              startActivity(phoneIntent);
```

so what is the code that will open the setting of the device on click button ? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that and tell me :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```